# how to convert request from byte[] to ByteBuf and send it to server using Netty

Tags: netty

I am new to netty, I am trying to send a request to TCP server using netty CLIENT, my TCP server accepts only byte array, how to send byte array as request and get the response from TCP server.

Comment: Share some code, eg server's inboundhandler.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytearray)`